# Accessing VM's terminal using putty in host OS?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, citrix

I am working on a project in which we logon to client's machine using `Cirtix receiver`. The machine which we connect to using `Citrix receiver` is basically a `Windows 7 machine`. Once we are in the client's windows box, inside that we have `virtual box`, in which VM has been added and which has all the needed software for us to do the development; for example JBOSS, database etc.

In the host machine (`windows 7`), we have `putty`, and using `putty` we sometimes login to the `VM` (i.e. terminal). The confusion which I have is as below:

We login to the VM terminal using IP address: `127.0.0.1`. This is where my confusion is. `127.0.0.1` normally is the IP address with which we can refer to the current machine; so how using this IP address we are able to connect to the VM which is added to the `virtual box`? Doesn't the VM which is in `virtualbox` has its own IP address with which we can connect to? Or is there some concept which I am not aware of.

Can anyone help me in understanding this? I am not well versed with virtualization, so for the gurus this might be a naive question.

Answer (score 1):

Every VM will have their uuids so to access the VM inside virtualBox or any hypervisor for that matter. so you can use  that particular VM uuid and u should be able to console to that VM.

in virtual box try below

You can use: VBoxManage list vms to list all currently registered VMs with their settings, names and UUIDs.

Once you know the UUID you can also start a vm by:

VBoxManage startvm  which is essentially same as: VBoxManage startvm "Name-of-vm"

Also Vm has two interfaces one loopback which will have an address of 127.0.0.1  and the rest of the interfaces so to access the VM with particular ip you need to assign an IP to that   VM interface and than try with that IP.Also you might have that port 22 open for that loopback ip so may be that is the reason you are able to connect on loopback

I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks for your answer; however I believe it might be related to "port forwarding" concept. As when I looked: Machine-> Settings -> Network -> (expand) Advanced -> Port Forwarding; there we have rules of port forwarding. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: yes that  allows you to connect over 22 This will NOT work if you already have ssh running on your host because the ports overlap